# Is it a good idea to recreate Win32's headers?

Tags: c, winapi, header

I'm finding myself doing more C/C++ code against Win32 lately, and coming from a C# background I've developed an obsession with "clean code" that is completely consistent, so moving away from the beautiful System.* namespace back to the mishmash of #defines that make up the Win32 API header files is a bit of a culture shock.

After reading through MSDN's alphabetical list of core Win32 functions I realised how simple Win32's API design actually is, and it's unfortunate that it's shrouded with all the cruft from the past 25 years, including many references to 16-bit programming that are completely irrelevant in today's 64-bit world.

I'm due to start a new C/C++ project soon, and I was thinking about how I could recreate Win32's headers on an as-needed basis. I could design it to be beautiful, and yet it would maintain 100% binary (and source) compatibility with existing programs (because the #defines ultimately resolve the same thing).

I was wondering if anyone had attempted this in the past (Google turned up nothing), or if anyone wanted to dissuade me from it.

Another thing I thought of, was how with a cleaner C Win32 API, it becomes possible to design a cleaner and easier to use C++ Win32 API wrapper on top, as there wouldn't be any namespace pollution from the old C Win32 items.

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I'm not doing this to improve compilation performance or for any kind of optimisation, I'm fully aware the compiler does away with everything that isn't used. My quest here is to have a Win32 header library that's a pleasure to work with (because I won't need to depress Caps-lock every time I use a function).

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example of a function or two here. It sounds more like that you're planning on writing what's essentially a thin wrapper library as a convenience - in a way, this isn't a lot different than what ATL or MFC do (or even window's own <windowsx.h>, which has wrappers for SendMessage and others). Pros: done well, it can boost productivity and help avoid common Win32 API traps (eg. getting the types correct with the registry APIs). The main downside is that someone else looking at your code may have no clue as to what you're doing - which may not be a problem in your case.

Comment: Looks like you got a pretty resounding no!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do this.

It may be possible, but it will take a long time and will probably lead to subtle bugs.

However, and more importantly, it will make your program utterly impossible for anyone other than you to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in doing this. Just because there's additional cruft doesn't mean it's compiled into the binary (anything unused will be optimized out). Furthermore, on the EXTREME off-chance that anything DOES change (I dunno, maybe `WM_INPUT`'s number changes) it's just a lot easier to use the system headers. Furthermore, what's more intuitive? I think `#include <windows.h>` is a lot easier to understand than `#include "a-windows-of-my-own.h"`.

Also, honestly you never should need to even look at the contents of windows.h. Yeah I've read it, yeah it's ugly as sin, but it does what I need it to and I don't need to maintain it.

Probably the ONLY downside of using the real `windows.h` is that it MAY slow down compilation by a few milliseconds.

Comment: More like a few seconds...per source file. :-)

Comment: @R: not if you're using pre-compiled headers.

Answer (score 3):

No.  What's the point?  Just include `<windows.h>`, and define a few macros like `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, `VC_EXTRALEAN`, `NOGDI`, `NOMINMAX`, etc. to prune out the things you don't want/need to speed up your compile times.

Answer (score 3):

Although the Win32 headers might be considered "messy", you pretty much never have to (or want to) look inside them. All you need to know is documented in the Win32 SDK. The exact contents of the header files are an implementation detail.

There is a ton of stuff in there that would be time-consuming and unnecessarily finicky to replicate, particularly relating to different versions of the Win32 SDK.

I recommend:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this is bad practice. Tidiness and brevity is achieved by keeping to the standard practice as much as possible, and leveraging as much as possible from the platform. You need to assume Microsoft to have the ultimate expertise in their own platform, with some aspects going beyond what you know right now. In simple words, it's their product and they know best.

By rolling your own:

- ... you branch off from Microsoft's API, so Microsoft could no longer deliver updates to you through their standard channels
- ... you may introduce bugs due to your own hubris, feeling you've figured something out while you haven't
- ... you'd be wasting a lot of time for no tangible benefit (as the C headers don't carry any overhead into the compiled binary)
- ... you'd eventually create a project that's less elegant

The most elegant code is one that carries more LOC of actual program logic and as little as possible LOC for "housekeeping" (i.e. code not directly related to the task at hand). Don't fail to leverage the Platform SDK headers to make your project more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This has been attempted in the past.

In its `include` directory, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) contains its own version of `windows.h`.  Presumably this exists to make the headers work with gcc.  I don't know if it will work with a Microsoft compiler.