# Syntax Error "=="

Tags: c++, syntax-error, game-engine

this is part of my code to my game engine that I am working on.  When I build/debug the code, it stops with a compiler error: "Camera.cpp(70): error C2059: syntax error : '==' "  and line 70 is the

`if ( near == far )` line. It also happens on line 75:

> `(if near == NULL || far == NULL)`

```
bool Camera::SetClippingPlanes( float near, float far )
{
    if (near == far)  //Line 70(First Error)
    { 
        MessageBox(NULL, L"ERROR: The far and near clipping planes cannot be equal!", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (near == NULL || far == NULL)  //Line 75(Second Error)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"ERROR: Near and/or Far clipping planes are null!", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            nearPane = near;
            farPane = far;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have other functions which use the == operator in the same way, but they do not receive an error.  Thanks if you have any suggestions...

Comment: @asawyer: No, you're thinking of `for` :)

Comment: @PeterAlexander No, I'm thinking about far pointers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many years ago (in a galaxy far, far away) `near` and `far` were keywords. It looks like your compiler still thinks they are - it's probably trying to be helpful.

You either need to pick different names, or figure out how to turn off this particular backward-compatible 'feature'.

Comment: Thanks for the info, also love the star wars reference! +1

Comment: Wow... I'm glad I didn't run into that one.  I wouldn't have thought to check that in years :p

Comment: Yeah, great star wars reference.  Thank you so much for the helpful answer. It worked exceptionally!

Answer (score 10):

You are coding for windows and in windows if you include windows.h or a file that include it( and certainly you include it, because you have a call to MessageBox ) then `far` and `near` are both defined in `windef.h` and you can't use them as variable names

Comment: actually windows don't use `far` and `near` any more it is there for compatibility, so you can undefine them using `#undef` and every thing will be ok but it is much cleaner to rename your variables, since it is true that 'Many years ago (in a galaxy far, far away) near and far were keywords...'

Comment: I'm reminded of a campaign I had earlier to rewrite Windows' header files ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146978/is-it-a-good-idea-to-recreate-win32s-headers ) . Maybe I should go ahead with it...

Comment: @Dai It is not an error of windows or something bad in it, Windows just try to keep compatibility with older systems and programs. Also you can do that but it take a very long time to get nothing special because you have to spend so much time to do this and then new SDK will arrive and you should replace your header files and beside that in that case no one else can use your code and all of this for what? keep `far` and `near`??

Answer (score 3):

It is also dangerous to compare floats with ==. Its not possible to represent every number with absolute precision. I believe the main ieee floating implementations are only good to 6 significant places. You'll find two ways or calculating what should be the same number will be out by 0.000001 or less and therefore wont be equal.

Comment: @StackUnderflow Maybe, but it might preemptively answer the next one :P